# Ubuntu php 5.6.4 to 5.6.5

Tags: upgrade, php, php7

How do I upgrade to php 5.6.5 on Ubuntu? Currently using version 5.6.4-4ubuntu6.4 
My repository is ubuntu.snet.uz!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways, either adding a PPA or enabling the development repository (found in software sources). Then apt-get update && apt-get install package-name.